# C - Mixed Text File Data > To Different Arrays (Int and String)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have just an ordinary "project.txt" file with this data:

```
Programming 10 3 4 5 4 3 2 4 5 2 3
Mathematics 8 3 3 4 5 3 2 2 3
Physics 6 3 4 5 3 4 5
Design 6 5 4 5 3 2 4
Logistics 8 3 4 5 3 1 1 2 3
```

Need to open this file, read and write all this data to arrays.
I need to somehow divide String and Integers from each other.
*** NO NEED FOR IT RIGHT NOW, but later I will need to write text and numbers to different files. ***NO NEED TO DO THIS NOW***

Just need to do it with 2 different int and char arrays, but I am sitting for few hours and can't find normal explanation of how to divide this string from other things.

Here is my code, can anybody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("C:\\Project\\project.txt", "r");
char arrayWords[140];
int i;

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Can't Read The File!");
    exit(0);
}

for (i = 0; i < 140; i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%s,", &arrayWords[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 140; i++){
    printf("Number is: %s\n\n", &arrayWords[i]);
}


fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

This is the output I get, it is really confusing (Some part of it)...

```
Number is: P13454324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 13454324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 3454324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 454324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 54324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 4324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 324523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 24523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 4523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 523M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 23M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 3M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: M833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 833453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 33453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 3453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 453223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 53223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 3223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 223P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 23P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 3P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: P6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 6345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 345345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 45345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 5345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 345D6545324L834531123

Number is: 45D6545324L834531123

Number is: 5D6545324L834531123
```

Think problem is in pointers, but don't know, I am kind of a beginner and can't find any problems.

Thanks to everyone

Comment: The way you are scanning with `%s`, then storing into the character-array `arrayWords` is not correct. I suggest you do some reading on C string handling, and `printf()`/`scanf()` codes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to parse these lists of space-separated numbers using the `strtol()` function.  This is a good solution because it handily sets a pointer to the *next* block of whitespace/non-number after the number it just converted. If there's no number to convert, it just sends back the original pointer. So the code tests for this to know when it's complete.

EDIT: Updated to handle name too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *number_str = "SomeWords 19 9 6 2 22 1 0 -4";
    char *ptr;
    char *next_number;
    int   numbers[1000];
    int   number_count = 0;
    char  name[100];

    next_number = number_str;

    // Copy off the name
    ptr = strchr(number_str, ' ');
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        strncpy(name, number_str, ptr-number_str);  // TODO - check bounds of name[]
        name[ptr-number_str] = '\0';

        // Point to the first number
        next_number = ptr+1;

        printf("Stored name [%s]\n", name);
    }

    // Then parse all the numbers
    do 
    {
        ptr = next_number;
        long num = strtol(ptr, &next_number, 10);
        if (ptr != next_number) // found one
        {
            numbers[number_count] = (int)num;
            printf("Stored %3d into numbers[%d]\n", numbers[number_count], number_count);
            number_count += 1;
        }
    } while(ptr != next_number);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Stored name [SomeWords]
Stored  19 into numbers[0]
Stored   9 into numbers[1]
Stored   6 into numbers[2]
Stored   2 into numbers[3]
Stored  22 into numbers[4]
Stored   1 into numbers[5]
Stored   0 into numbers[6]
Stored  -4 into numbers[7]
```

Comment: I don't have problems with int, I have lines which begin with string and continues with numbers, I can use char to output whole lines, but I can't take that first string and put it in one array and later take those numbers on the same line and put them in another array, that is my problem

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a line from the file into a `char *buffer`.

Comment: Yep, now I can somehow focus on one line, but still there is a problem.
I still have mixed string, with letters and numbers, it starts with word PROGRAMMING and continues with few numbers, How can I take only this programming and add it to string array ?